# Is there a simple way to pass data from children to parent component?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component

I've ben struggling to pass data from children back to parent component whole morning, but with no luck. So I need your help guys, how to properly do this.

**Parent component**

```
<template>
<dropin
        wrapperClass="constrain"
        :authToken="authToken"
        :collectCardHolderName="true"
        :enableDataCollector="true"
        :enablePayPal="true"
>
</dropin>
<button type="submit" style="padding-top: 1rem;" id="submitTransaction"
        @click="getBrainTreeNounce">Verify
</button>
</template>
```

when you execute getBrainTreeNounce this method executes children component function via $emit

```
//methods
getBrainTreeNounce() {
  this.$emit('tokenize');
},
```

**Children component**

```
created() {
    this.dropinCreate();
    this.$parent.$on('tokenize', () => {
        this.dropinRequestPaymentMethod();
    });
},
// now this method happens
dropinRequestPaymentMethod() {
    this.dropinInstance.requestPaymentMethod((requestErr, payload) => {
        if (requestErr) {
            this.errorMessage = 'There was an error setting up the client instance. Message: ' + requestErr.message;
            this.$emit('bt.error', this.errorMessage);
            return;
        }
        this.paymentPayload = payload;
        // got payload, now send it back to parent???
        $this.$emit('returnPayload', this.paymentPayload); //??
        return this.paymentPayload
    });
},
```

I have tried various thing like creating new event and listening in parent component or returning the data, etc... but no luck for now. So is there some simple way to return data back to my parent component?

If you have any additional informations, please let me know and I will provide. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a working example of child passing data to parent during mount. can you expand on why this is not working for you?

```js
Vue.component('Child', {
  template: '#child',
 data: function() {
  return {
     msg: "HELLO"
    }
  },
  mounted() {
   this.$emit('onmounted', this.msg)
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
   childMsg: null
  },
  methods:{
   onChildMounted(msg){
     this.childMsg = msg;
    }
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <Child @onmounted="onChildMounted"></Child>
  <h2>
    Parent hears <code>{{childMsg}}</code>
  </h2>
</div>

<script type="text/x-template" id="child">
<div id="child">
  <h2>
    Child says <code>{{msg}}</code>
  </h2>
</div>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have figure it out how to do it. In my child component i had to call this.$parent.$emit so now my function looks like this

```
dropinRequestPaymentMethod() {
    this.dropinInstance.requestPaymentMethod((requestErr, payload) => {
        if (requestErr) {
            this.errorMessage = 'There was an error setting up the client instance. Message: ' + requestErr.message;
            this.$emit('bt.error', this.errorMessage)   ;
            return;
        }
        this.paymentPayload = payload;
        // I have added this line
        this.$parent.$emit('sendPayloadToParent', this.paymentPayload);
    });
},
```

And now you can fetch data in your parent component like this

```
mounted: function () {
    this.$on('sendPayloadToParent', function (payloadData) {
        console.log('caught in parent', payloadData)
    });
}
```